# Is is possible to treat double clicks as single clicks in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm learning JavaScript. I noticed that if I click on an object multiple times, quickly, some clicks are captured as double clicks. Is it possible to capture all clicks in JavaScript as single clicks only?

Comment: Look at the `mouseDown` event rather than the `click` event.

Comment: On IE if I click the left mouse button twice quickly the events are: onmousedown, onmouseup, onclick, onmouseup, ondblclick.

Comment: I need to capture: onmousedown, onmouseup, onclick, onmousedown, onmouseup, onclick. If I disable ondblclick then I get: onmousedown, onmouseup, onclick, onmouseup. onmousedown is missing.

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery, you could create a double click event handler on the document and then prevent that default behavior:

```
$(document).dblclick(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Handler for .dblclick() called and ignored.');
});
```

[Double click in the example](http://jsfiddle.net/gNE6m/) to see the result.

Comment: I would like to learn Javascript without any libraries first.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to solve this problem.

1) Using "return false;" statement on double click event.
Example:

```
<button id="your button id" onclick="yourfuntion()" ondblclick="return false;" >My Button</button>
```

2) Disable the button/object in the start of your main function and in the end of the function enable it again.

Example:

```
<button id="your button id" onclick="yourfuntion()">My Button</button>

<script>

function yourfuntion() { document.getElementById("your button id").disabled = true; 
//your javascript code 

document.getElementById("your button id").disabled = false;}

</script>
```